# Run a PHP-script from a PHP-script without blocking

Tags: php, apache, system-calls

I'm building a spider which will traverse various sites and data mining them.

Since I need to get each page separately this could take a VERY long time (maybe 100 pages).
I've already set the set_time_limit to be 2 minutes per page but it seems like apache will kill the script after 5 minutes no matter.

This isn't usually a problem since this will run from cron or something similar which does not have this time limit. However I would also like the admins to be able to start a fetch manually via a HTTP-interface.

It is not important that apache is kept alive for the full duration, I'm, going to use AJAX to trigger a fetch and check back once in a while with AJAX.

My problem is how to start the fetch from within a PHP-script without the fetch being terminated when the script calling it dies.

Maybe I could use system('script.php &') but I'm not sure it will do the trick.
Any other ideas?

Comment: A friend told med about nohup, think that'll work?
That is system('nohup php -f script.php &')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    $cmd = "php myscript.php $params > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &";

    # when we call this particular command, the rest of the script 
    # will keep executing, not waiting for a response
    shell_exec($cmd);
```

What this does is sends all the STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null, and your script keeps executing. Even if the 'parent' script finishes before myscript.php, myscript.php will finish executing.

Comment: don't forget to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php on $params

Comment: But it will fall on it's arse if the session terminates. And can no longer be signalled with a HUP (e.g. to stop gracefully). A better solution is to attach it to a different session header e.g. 'echo php myscript.php | at now'

Comment: ....and you would not believe how complicated and flaky Erik's suggestion will get if you launch it from apache.

Comment: @symcbean: What do you mean by "if the session terminates"? The calling script can end and the called script continues to run to completion.

Comment: @symcbean: I'd like to learn, so why dont you back up your comments? I've this identical piece of code running on a production site for a year .. it gets called 100+ times per hour and its never exhibited any problems.

Comment: "If it terminates" The caking script should end if its started from a web page - but the **PROCESS** may continue to serve other requests before being recycled (how many depends on the config).
http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html

Comment: I can just report that this worked fine and the spider crawls just fine ever after the calling scripts has finished.

Big thanks to you Erik :)

Comment: Running PHP scripts through CLI consumes a LOT of memory , around 5 to 10 MB of ram (32bit os) and double of that on 64 bit OS. if you are doing crawling i suggest you use python with threading, you can start a server using 'twisted' library, and send tcp sockets to it via php, containing all your params, which will be parsed by the python server and start a thread for every crawler you need, this way you eleminate the php over head and excessive memory usage, on top of that you will be able to control how many threads you want to be open (timeouts/network transmission rate)

Comment: how would you do that on windows ?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use exec you can use a php built in function !

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

this will tell the script to resume even if the connection between the browser and the server is dropped ;)

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Comment: @patrick not at all, the OP asked how to run a another process  without blocking; not how to keep the script running even after the user closes the connection