# How to share variable in PHP from webpage script to script running permanently from the command line

Tags: php, variables, command-line, shared, permanent

I have a script running permanently from command line on a web server.
There is a loop checking new stuff in DB.
To save some load I need to add a condition not to check the DB if there is no reason.
When the change occurs I need immediate reaction, however it might happen that there is no change for a few hours.
And yes, it is not possible to do it in the webpage_script.php :)

The idea is to use some kind or a SUPERGLOBAL variable and in webpage_script.php save TRUE to that variable and then check it in that condition in permanently_running_script_on_the_same_server.php.

However I didn't find any variable that can be used for that reason... when I try to use session_id('whateverisinhereblahblab') - to share the session, the webpage_script.php will not get loaded as the session is probably continually occupied...

webpage_script.php

```
$the_shared_variable['whatever'] === FALSE;
if ($something_happens){
  $the_shared_variable['whatever'] === TRUE;
}
```

permanently_running_script_on_the_same_server.php

```
while (true) {
    if($the_shared_variable['whatever'] === TRUE){



    }
}
```

Comment: make `$the_shared_variable` a value from the database

Comment: Does the permanently running script do anything other than respond to the signal from the web script? If not, have the web script start it with `shell_exec` and run it to completion as a background task. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2440023/14853083

Comment: Tangentially Perpendicular - yes, this is just a marginal part of the job...

Comment: Lawrence Cherone - can you say a little bit more please... i guess you do not mean just select from DB and assign to a variable... is there any kind of premanent link from PHP to DB?

Comment: A super global is just a variable like any other, except that it's available in all scopes within your scrip. Setting a value in one script won't make it available in any other script. And the concept of sessions doesn't exist (or even make sense) when calling a script though CLI. You need to store the value somewhere (an in-memory cache like redis or similar might work). If it's possible, you could also trigger a cron job every nth seconds instead of running a while loop like that (since PHP isn't really optimized for having a "main loop"-like-style-script that).